# Clone a object JSON but until its 5th key-value

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON that has more than 10 key-values, I need to create a copy of this but limiting it until the 5th key-value.

Input:

```
var object1 = {
  "1a": 1,
  "2b": 2,
  "3c": 1,
  "4d": 2,
  "5e": 1,
  "6f": 2,
  "7g": 1,
  "8h": 2,
  "9i": 1,
  "10j": 2
};
```

Desired output:

```
var object2 = {
  "1a": 1,
  "2b": 2,
  "3c": 1,
  "4d": 2,
  "5e": 1,
};
```

I'm thinking about creating a new one key per key by using a for until 10th. Any thoughts?

Comment: start a counter. for prop in yourObject {clone prop value, and counter++} if counter > 5; break;

Comment: I might be wrong, but this can be trickier than expected. Orders of members aren't necessary respected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could slice the array of entries and rebuild a new object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var object = { "1a": 1, "2b": 2, "3c": 1, "4d": 2, "5e": 1, "6f": 2, "7g": 1, "8h": 2, "9i": 1, "10j": 2 },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).slice(0, 5));
    
console.log(result);
```

The same with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var object = { "1a": 1, "2b": 2, "3c": 1, "4d": 2, "5e": 1, "6f": 2, "7g": 1, "8h": 2, "9i": 1, "10j": 2 },
    result = Object.assign({}, ...Object
        .entries(object)
        .slice(0, 5)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries is not a function`. I'm using firefox 60

Comment: @Cid, use `Object.assign` and map new objects. please see edit.

Comment: @Kobe Your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @Cid It was a joke :)

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use something like this, it's a relatively standard implementation by making use of the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

What's good about this solution is that it's so simple that even beginners can make sense of it.

```js
var object1 = {
  "1a": 1,
  "2b": 2,
  "3c": 1,
  "4d": 2,
  "5e": 1,
  "6f": 2,
  "7g": 1,
  "8h": 2,
  "9i": 1,
  "10j": 2
};

var object2 = Object.keys(object1).reduce((o, k, i) => {
  i < 5 ? o[k] = object1[k] : null;
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(object2);
```